# Insert a table row with text in cells when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made a function to dynamically create this table and a button with a function to display texts inside the table shown as a message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">

</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML = "please";
    cell2.innerHTML = "put";
    cell3.innerHTML = "information";
    cell4.innerHTML = "here";
    cell5.innerHTML = "fill";
    cell6.innerHTML = "up";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My goal is to  create a function to dynamically create a 6 or 5 input boxes with a table and make a button use function as well to display the text inside to display as a message

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Note that we can review your existing working code, but we cannot help you add new features to your code.

Answer (score 1):

So you want for example 6 inputs and create a table from it with the input when you click on a button.

(plain javascript):

This way it doesn't matter how many input fields you have. It will get all of them. I added some comments so you can understand what's going on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">

</table>
<br>

<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<button onclick="Display_inputs()">Try it</button>

<script>
function Display_inputs() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    //Gets all the input fields
 var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    //start from 0 till the length of input fields
  for(var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++){
     //creates a new cell every time it loops so in this case
        //it loops 6 times
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
     cell.innerHTML = input[i].value;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helps me a lot.But I still got a question. you see, i have two functions need to done, one displays the message which already solved.another one is on file load it should invoke a JS function to dynamically create a table with some default text.(For example : Put information here...)

Comment: You can make make another function for that and loop that  the same way but instead of outputting the input[i].value you can make a variable 'information here' and display that instead

to load it directly you need to use _onload_ 
more info [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)